# Range $~\theta~$ and radial velocity to $x ~y~ z$

Tags: coordinate-systems, euclidean-algorithm, clustering

I am writing a code for $~3~$ dimensional clustering. I have radar data in range $~\theta~$ and velocity domain. But to do clustering, I need it to be in the Cartesian form to use the euclidean distance. As for $~r~$ and $~\theta~$, I can do $(r~\sin(\theta))$ and $(r~\cos(\theta))$ to get $~x~$ and $~y~$.

I am not sure how to get the $~z~$ axis here using the radial velocity.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Best,
V

Comment: Please use Latex

Comment: $r$ and $\theta$ alone won't locate a point in $3$-space.  Don't you have something else, like altitude?